# ASP.NET trying to create a report with Totals And Sub Totals on the web

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting

In MS Access we have a simple report:

```
Manufacture | Model | Wheels | Serial
Man1 | aaa | 4 | 111
Man1 | aaa | 4 | 112
Man1 | bbb |2 | 123
Total Models: 3  Total Wheels: 10
Man2 | asd| 8 | 1145
.......
And so on until the totals at the bottom:
Total models: 55   |Total Wheels: 245
```

I want to convert this to work on the web. I’ve got the data on a gridview, but cannot get the sub totals or totals. Is there something that can be set in the Columns’ properties?
Is the  gridview even the best choice for this or would you use a different control?
I’m using c# in Web Developer 2010 Express and the data is coming from SQL Server if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

http://tinyurl.com/7olot6v

Here's an example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx

It's in VB.NET but converting the idea over shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. e.g. Adding that the OP should set `ShowFooter = true` and calculate the totals and set the values on rowdatabound

Comment: Thanks Brent, but if I understand that correctly it only gives lets me add a footer. I need a 'sub footer' if you will between each Manufacture in this example.

Comment: Gotcha, a sub-total row. If you plan to do a lot of reporting check out the Reports toolbox item. You may be better off utilizing SQL Reporting for this. You don't actually need SQL Server, its just a control and file designed specifically for reporting. Otherwise you may need to look into 3rd party controls, I would start with the reporting toolbox first and then go from there.

Comment: Ok now I feel foolish for asking, but does it have another name other then SQL Reporting, as I can't find this in my tool box

Comment: @jimmy If you right click on your project in Visual Studio and click on Add New Item do you have a template group called Reporting?  If so there should be an entry for "Report" inside there.  That allows you to build the report. If you edit a form/page the toolbox item should be called Reporting and contain a Report Viewer control.  My concern now that I re-read your question is that Visual Web Developer may not contain the reporting controls or tools, I'm just not sure, I don't have that edition.

Comment: nope, not there. So I assume it's just not an option in this edition. I'll have a look and see if any 3rd party apps work.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. I did find alink for you that might help without going into 3rd party land: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072603-1.aspx